# Add active class to button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add an active class to my buttons in react, however this doesn't add my class and does nothing when I click on a button.

I get no errors in the console and I have similar code for radio buttons which does work but I am not sure how to modify that code to work for my group of buttons.

I can see in the react dev tools that my class `nav-active` is being applied to the first button as expected but I dont see the black bg color on the button:

`<Styled.button isActive="1" className="nav-active onChlick=bound setActiveTab()>`

```
 const TestBtn = styled(Button)`
  height:40px;
  width:auto;
  background:#ff00ff;
`

class TopCategories extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { isActive: 1 }
    this.setActiveTab = this.setActiveTab.bind(this)
  }

  setActiveTab(id) {
    this.setState({ isActive: id })
 }

  render() {
    const items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'tab-1', text: 'text', value: '1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'tab-2', text: 'text', value: '2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'tab-3', text: 'text', value: '3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'tab-4', text: 'text', value: '4' },
  { id: 5, name: 'tab-5', text: 'text', value: '5' },
]

const tabs = items.map(item =>
  <div key={item.id}>
    <TestBtn
      isActive={item.id}
      className={this.state.isActive === item.id ? 'nav-active' : ''}
      onClick={this.setActiveTab}
    >
      {item.name}
    </TestBtn>
  </div>,
)

return (
  <Container>
    <Wrapper>
      {tabs}
    </Wrapper>
  </Container>
)
}
}


export default TopCategories

styles.css

.nav-active { background:#000;}
```

Comment: have you cheked `isActive` get updated when you click and what value it printing. Try for both `item.id` and `isactive`

Comment: Is `.isActive` the class you want to add? There's a snippet `.isActive { background:#000;}`

Comment: sorry should be nav-active as the class I'm trying to add

Comment: Are you declaring that in a css or inside the js?

Comment: it is in a seperate css file

Comment: Does your `TestBtn` component pass the given `onClick` handler the `isActive` prop (id)? If not, then `setActiveTab()` is probably receiving the synthetic event object as the `id` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You just need send your id in yor function setActiveTab(id).

```
onClick={() => this.setActiveTab(item.id)}
```

And i advice you to change key from item.id to index which you send with arrow function.

```
const tabs = items.map(item => // const tabs = items.map((item, index) =>
  <div key={item.id}> // <div key={index}>
    <TestBtn
      isActive={item.id}
      className={this.state.isActive === item.id ? 'nav-active' : ''}
      onClick={this.setActiveTab}
    >
      {item.name}
    </TestBtn>
  </div>, // what is , ?
)
```

Comment: Changed the onClick doesn't seem to work and airbnb linter won't allow the key change to index

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/75231/). Is this what you need?

Comment: perfect thanks! The problem with the class not being applied was with my styled component not applying the nav-active class